# How to display current user in NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, service, windows-services

I've created a Windows Service that successfully runs my NodeJS app. Its *Log On As* is set to **Local System**.

The issue, however, is that when I get the current user name (via `require("os").userInfo().username`), it returns SYSTEM, and not the current user that's using the app.

Is there anyway around this?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reconcile this by using the **node-sspi** module, instead of the **OS** module for Node.js

The former module was able to correctly pull the username of the current user.